# web based ide for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-ide

Does a web based IDE exist for ruby on rails development?

Comment: Are you looking for an online browser based IDE to do Rails development?

Comment: I made a [comparative table of JS web IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Javascript_IDE#Comparison), the ones with (1) support ruby. There are 3 as of March 2013.

Comment: try https://koding.com

Answer (score 9):

try https://koding.com/

Awesome UI with cool feature  :)

Answer (score 8):

3 years later : yes, it exists : [Nitrous.io](https://www.nitrous.io/?ref=grgf5Q95DdY) (disclaimer : copy/paste the link and remove the ref part if you don't want to help me getting early access )

You can find a short presentation video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GIylBBh2zk)

Edit: it's now called [Nitrous.io](https://www.nitrous.io/?ref=grgf5Q95DdY) and it's out of private beta since 26/07/13

Answer (score 1):

The only one I know of is [Heroku](http://heroku.com/).

Comment: not quite what I was asking for, but thanks!

Comment: Then be more specific - by web-based IDE I understand something like Eclipse, but running in a browser (like jpartogi said). Heroku fits that description (look at it's features on http://herokugarden.com/features).

Comment: I never saw any edit code online stuff when I looked at heroku...

Comment: I investigated this further and this is what I stumbled upon: http://herokugarden.com/transition/faq#online-editor
So they are in the process of upgrading their services - since the online editor was a key feature of the previous version, I'm sure it will reappear in the future - you can ask around on their Support pages: http://support.heroku.com/portal.